# How to append user - input into a file Haskell

Tags: file, haskell, append

I'm trying to append some input taken from the user, into a file. but I receive a strange error... which says that append can take only 2 parameters, and not 4.

this is the code:

```
ame :: IO ()

ame = do   

    putStr "Enter the file name: "
    name <- getLine
    putStrLn "Do you want to add new records? "
    question <- getLine
    if question == "yes" then do
        putStrLn "Enter your records:"
        newRec <- getLine
        appendFile name ('\n':newRec)

        putStrLn "enter something new: "
        something <- getLine
        appendFile name ('\n':something)

        putStrLn "enter something new again: "
        something2 <- getLine
        appendFile name ('\n':something2)
        putStrLn "a"
    else
        putStr "b"
```

can someone help me with this?

Comment: Please don't delete your question this time - hold on while I answer! (I had written a full answer but you deleted the question while I was writing)

Comment: yea. sorry. I removed the first one because at some point it worked. but then.. another problem occurred..

Comment: It's the same problem... hold on....

Comment: @bheklilr Edit rolled back because it deleted the problem!

Comment: @AndrewC I saw that, I hadn't realized that whitespace was the problem before reformatting the code.

Comment: @Simple don't worry, most of us experienced this. If you keep it up, the day is not so far that you think: "What stupid idea is this thing with the braces and semicolons?" I promise!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use spaces not tabs**

You have used a mixture of tabs and spaces in your file. This tends to cause confusion because you, your editor and Haskell tend to interpret these differently.

Replace all the tabs in your code with the appropriate number of spaces to line it up and you will stop getting these mysterious errors.

**Make your editor indent for you**

A lot of editors have a setting where the tab key gives you an appropriate number of spaces, and pressing enter adds whitespace to line you up with the previous text, and backspace unindents you to the previous indentation. These settings are very handy - turn them on.

**Your error messages: why**

In particular, in your first question, it thought `appendFile` was a pattern, and in this version it thinks `putStrLn "enter something new again: "` is part of the previous line, because it's indented further than you think. If you click edit on your question (without changing anything) you'll see that it doesn't line up.

Comment: No, editors are very inconsistent. Layout is lovely. I don't miss `{`, `;` or `}` at all. I just don't. When I'm using them in other languages, I feel I've gone back to the time of the ark, it's all so unnecessary.

Comment: @Simplle It's no more delicate than any other language.  If in C I had `some_function(a, b, c d);` where I missed a single character, it wouldn't compile.  Python also enforces whitespace, and while you can successfully mix whitespace it often leads to problems with strange error messages from the parser.

Comment: I know what you mean..
but being new with haskell.. you start wondering what's wrong with your code. you are trying to get 2 inputs from users and then you want to get another input. and this time it doesn't work. 
that's why I've also deleted my first post. I've tried to compile the code and it didn't work. I pasted the code here. then someone told that it works. and I copied the code back in my text editor. and it did worked. then I've added something new.. and it stopped working again...
anyway. now it works fine. thanks guys

Comment: @Simplle Someone edited that one too I think. If you indent your code in a question by four spaces it all looks like code - on Stack Overflow people tend to edit your question to make it more readable, and of course, they would replace tabs with spaces to match up the indentation again, because adding four spaces at the start breaks the indentation of your tabs, if you're inconsistent. By the way, using tabs is _OK_ if you're super consistent, it's just easier and more human-error tolerant to use spaces.

Comment: @AndrewC It doesn't really matter if you use tabs or spaces, what matters is that you only use one of them (for indenting). Anything else is just asking for trouble.

Comment: @Cubic Yes and no - What matters is that you're consistent within each function; you can use whatever you like. Tabs are asking for trouble in that a subblock indented by 16 feels too far, so you're tempted to add a few spaces, then you edit the code later and can't see visually how you did it previously. Tabs are asking for asking for trouble. This is coming from someone who used tabs and spaces happily for well over a decade before deciding it wasn't worth it. I've not looked back, particularly in light of good editor settings.